# Define a variable in build.gradle and use that value in network XML file

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

In build.gradle file I have to define a boolean value

```
buildConfigField("boolean", "SKIP_SSL_CHECK", "true")
```

so I want o access it in the network.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="${SKIP_SSL_CHECK}" /
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

i want to make that value alter as per the build variant
for debug, it should be true and for others, it should be false.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option for manifest placeholders or other types of variables in XML resources.

However, you can have multiple versions of the resource in source sets tied to specific build variants, with different values for `cleartextTrafficPermitted`:

- In `app/src/debug/res/xml/`, put the `debug` version of your resource
- In `app/src/main/res/xml/`, put the `release` version of your resource

Comment: i have tried this one also but somehow it works fine when I run the code from the studio but when Jenkins create a build and share it then it is not working(showing SSL error not able to skip the ssl check)